# How do you have an image cover half a section and a text container in the other half?

Tags: web

I'm currently making a simple website, but I have to have an image covering one half of a section and text on the other side.
How do I do that?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put the img inside a section or div, and then simple apply some CSS to float that image to the left.

Adding `width: 50%;` makes the img width half of it's parent div (in this case, `<section>`)

Here is an excellent write up on it: [clicky](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/).

Here is my working jsfiddle: [clicky](https://jsfiddle.net/8q6hvpv3/4/)

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div>
    <img class="floatLeft" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/457164810052857856/cXNMHcHF.jpeg">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do...
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.floatLeft {
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
}
```